# Android Studio 2.2.2 error "Unable to locate mode 0" on rendering preview after update

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-appcompat

I update Android Studio to version 2.2.2 and after that I changed `compileSdkVersion` and buildToolVersion to 25.0.0 and `appcompat-V7:25.0.0`, Now I can't build project and run project perfectly but I have an error on during rendering activities that contain `RecyclerView`. here is error detail:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to locate mode 0
>       at android.view.DisplayInfo.findMode(DisplayInfo.java:458)
>       at android.view.DisplayInfo.getMode(DisplayInfo.java:445)
>       at android.view.Display.getRefreshRate(Display.java:648)
>       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onAttachedToWindow(RecyclerView.java:2392)
>       at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:15392)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2953)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2960)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2960)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2960)
>       at android.view.AttachInfo_Accessor.setAttachInfo(AttachInfo_Accessor.java:42)
>       at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:333)
>       at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:429)
>       at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:389)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:548)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:533)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:966)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:533)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$53(RenderTask.java:659)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Does anyone run into the same problem? any solution!?

Comment: I got the same problem, but I am not using a RecyclerView :|

Comment: You can check the issue in the Google Tracker: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=225753 The error is only related to the IDE

Comment: as @GabrieleMariotti mentioned, it is on going issue and no temporary fix has been released yet. For me I simply comment out RecyclerView temporarily and then i am able to see preview. Once u finished, just uncomment it back. ;-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's a bug of Android Support Library version 25.0.0, and have fixed in new 25.0.1!

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.1'
```

Comment: It's not the first time Google has this huge issues with the libraries. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

In build.gradle(Module:App) change the version of RecyclerView from 25 to 24.

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.0.0'
```

Comment: I'm using last version and I want answer  for last version, I know how to I can use previous version

Answer (score -3):

same Problem here. Temporarily fixed it by setting my build.gradle to compile appcompat-v7:24.0.3 instead of the 25.0.0. 
Hopes this helps.